Why isn't the circle redrawn in the window? (Fltk/c++)
I wrote this code to make the circle move along the x axis as many pixels as those moved on the dial. All the variables seem fine but the circle never redraws itself.
I would like that by moving the dial the circle on the screen also moves at the same time, as if it were doing a shift.
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Widget.H>
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Dial.H>
#include <iostream>  // Necessario per std::cout

// Classe per il widget che disegnerà il cerchio
class CircleWidget : public Fl_Widget {
public:
    int radius;

    CircleWidget(int X, int Y, int R)
        : Fl_Widget(X, Y, 2 * R, 2 * R), radius(R) {}

    // Funzione di disegno del cerchio
    void draw() override {
        fl_color(FL_RED); // Colore del cerchio
        fl_circle(x() + radius, y() + radius, radius); // Disegna il cerchio
    }

    // Aggiorna la posizione orizzontale del cerchio e ridisegna
    void update_position(int new_x) {
        this->position(new_x, y()); // Cambia la posizione del widget lungo l'asse x
        redraw(); // Ridisegna il cerchio nella nuova posizione
    }
};

// Callback per il controllo tramite il Dial
void dial_callback(Fl_Widget* dial, void* circle_widget) {
    Fl_Dial* d = (Fl_Dial*)dial;
    CircleWidget* circle = (CircleWidget*)circle_widget;

    // Sposta il cerchio in base al valore del dial
    int new_x = (int)d->value();
    
    // Stampa il valore di new_x
    std::cout << "Valore di new_x: " << new_x << std::endl;

    circle->update_position(new_x); // Aggiorna la posizione orizzontale del cerchio
}

int main() {
    // Crea una finestra con sfondo nero
    Fl_Window* window = new Fl_Window(400, 300, "Dial e Cerchio");
    window->color(FL_BLACK);  // Imposta il colore di sfondo a nero

    // Crea un cerchio iniziale
    CircleWidget* circle = new CircleWidget(50, 50, 50); // Cerchio con raggio 50

    // Crea un dial
    Fl_Dial* dial = new Fl_Dial(300, 200, 80, 80, "Dial");
    dial->range(0, 300);  // Imposta il range del dial da 0 a 300
    dial->value(50);      // Imposta un valore iniziale
    dial->callback(dial_callback, circle); // Associa una callback per aggiornare il cerchio

    window->end();
    window->show();

    return Fl::run();
}


For me the circle moves when the dial is changed. However, its background is not redrawn and thus the previously drawn circles are not erased. Tested with FLTK 1.4 (git) and 1.3.9 (git branch-1.3) on Linux and Windows (cross-compiled using wine).
You can fix this issue by adding parent()->redraw() in update_position(). Just in case you're using a similar approach in a project where the window is resizable you should also add parent()->init_sizes();. This is necessary whenever you reposition widgets inside their (resizable) parent groups.
New code:
    void update_position(int new_x) {
        this->position(new_x, y()); // Cambia la posizione del widget lungo l'asse x
        redraw(); // Ridisegna il cerchio nella nuova posizione
        parent()->redraw();
        parent()->init_sizes();
    }

However, this is not very efficient because the entire window is redrawn whenever the dial is changed. You can improve this by adding another group "around" the circle widget so only this group is redrawn, like this code in main():
    Fl_Group *cgroup = new Fl_Group(0, 50, window->w(), 2*50);
    cgroup->box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
    cgroup->color(FL_YELLOW);

    // Crea un cerchio iniziale
    CircleWidget* circle = new CircleWidget(50, 50, 50); // Cerchio con raggio 50
    cgroup->end();

Note that I added a yellow background to cgroup to demonstrate where the group is located.
Note also that it's possible to erase (i.e. redraw) only a specific area of a widget or window by using Fl_Widget::damage(...) but I'm leaving this to the reader.
@OP: if this doesn't solve your issue, please add more info about your FLTK version and system (OS) platform.
EDIT: this version works with Fl_Widget::damage() (showing only the modified method):
  void update_position(int new_x) {
    window()->damage(FL_DAMAGE_EXPOSE|FL_DAMAGE_CHILD, x() - 2,   y() - 2, w() + 4, h() + 4);
    window()->damage(FL_DAMAGE_EXPOSE|FL_DAMAGE_CHILD, new_x - 2, y() - 2, w() + 4, h() + 4);
    position(new_x, y()); // Cambia la posizione del widget lungo l'asse x
    parent()->init_sizes();
  }


Note that this doesn't work as expected if the window is made resizable and is resized smaller than the original size but I'm not going to (try to) "fix" this since this code is only for demonstration purposes.

I tried but it didn't work... I think the problem is in the quick change of values of dial. But I don't know how to fix it.

Which version didn't work? The one with redraw() or the one with damage() - or both? The quick change of the dial shouldn't cause any problems. As I wrote before, please post your system and FLTK version so we can try on that platform. If you are using an older FLTK version, please try to upgrade to the latest stable (1.3.9) or use a 1.4.x snapshot. Also, please make sure to remove all potentially conflicting FLTK versions from your system and always start a new build of FLTK in a fresh build folder.

Both. Unlucky I must use the 1.3.8 version

But your advices were good.

PS: For further questions I suggest to ask in our user group fltk.general (https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral) or on GitHub Discussions in the Q&A section (https://github.com/fltk/fltk/discussions/categories/q-a).

If both versions don't work for you then something must be wrong with your system. Please see my advice above on where to ask further so we can guide you better.

First of all: On my PC it simply draws the circle again and again and this ends up in hundreds of drawn circles.
I slightly modified your code to get a moving circle which is erased on the old position and redrawn on the new with:
    void update_position(int new_x) {
        hide();
        this->position(new_x, y()); // Cambia la posizione del widget lungo l'asse x
        show();
        //redraw(); // Ridisegna il cerchio nella nuova posizione
    }  

I had installed fltk 1.3.8 which is the default on fedora.
BTW: Thanks for showing this code! I was not aware that fltk supports a canvas like drawing with real objects and not only having some handcrafted draw methods. Great!

Interesting solution, but although this works I wouldn't recommend it because hiding and showing a widget may result in flicker and is likely less efficient.

FWIW, regarding "drawing with real objects": you can create any widget with a complex drawing method. Often it is useful to derive such a widget from Fl_Box rather than Fl_Widget because Fl_Box can be configured to draw the background w/o having to do it yourself in the widget's draw() method. Even more complex widgets can be derived from Fl_Group etc..

@AlbrechtSchlosser: BTW: Is there already a method to find out that an event ( like mouse click) was done inside something we have drawn? For example, I draw a filled circle, which as I know would be done by using fl_pie, can we know somehow that the mouse was inside the circle when the event was generated? It is easy for a circle to do this by our own, but for complex things like a line with different types of line endings, we have to do a lot of calculations. Maybe there is already something. Thanks!

No, sorry, there are two overloads of Fl::event_inside() (https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/group__fl__events.html#ga143c28ca9e41cb919be1c4c72227a475) but both check only a rectangular area.

@AlbrechtSchlosser: Is there a chance to use something from the algorithms which fills the items? Or is fltk forwarding the drawing things directly to deeper layers of "whatever"? Background: I need something that does the same as goocanvasmm or tk::canvas. The problem is that gnome did not support canvas anymore :-( Maybe we can talk on a better channel?

As I wrote above: For further questions I suggest to ask in our user group fltk.general (https://groups.google.com/g/fltkgeneral) or on GitHub Discussions in the Q&A section (https://github.com/fltk/fltk/discussions/categories/q-a). These platforms are not interactive like IRC but they are pretty responsive and watched by FLTK devs. You can use 'fltk.general' as a mailing list or with its web frontend.
